# A question related to using self adjoint operators to deduce eigenvalues of a related matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying quiz questions of last year in subject linear algebra and i was unable to solve this particular problem.
I am studying through textbook Hoffman and kunze.

It's image:

[image]

> I thought initially of multiplying and dividing by (A*+iI) but that doesn't seems to yield anything and also there is no surety why inverse of (A*+I) exists?

I am clueless on how this problem can be solved. Kindly give some hint.

Comment: Google helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103421/eigenvalues-of-product-of-two-complex-matrices

Comment: if you re-scale each matrix by $-i$ and $i$  respectively this is the standard Cayley Transform for skew Hermitian matrices.